# How convert 2020-08-18T08:00:00 to miliseconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, momentjs, data-conversion

How can I convert this date format (2020-08-18T08:00:00), to milliseconds in javascript?

I'm using momentJS, but I haven't found how to do this conversion.

Thanks!!!

Comment: That date format doesn't contain digits that specify milliseconds.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for this?  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: Your input is lacking a timezone offset, so it cannot meaningfully/reliably be converted to milliseconds-past-the-epoch.

Comment: In moment.js you'd do `moment('2020-08-18T08:00:00').format('X')` or `moment('2020-08-18T08:00:00').unix()`, [RTFM](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Date and use `getTime()`. Because of absence of timezone it's calculated on the users timezone and not UTC or serverside timezone.

**Edited:** Because different browser (e.g. Safari and Firefox) produce different results [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) I changed my code so is the date now generated by a secure method by programatical and not automatic parsing of the datestring. 
In the old version I had: `let date = new Date(dateStr);` which works on the most browser but not on all as RobG mentioned.

```js
let dateStr = '2020-08-18T08:00:00';

let parts = dateStr.split('T');
let datParts = parts[0].split('-');
let timeParts = parts[1].split(':');

let date = new Date(datParts[0], datParts[1]-1, datParts[2], timeParts[0], timeParts[1], timeParts[2]);

let ms = date.getTime()
console.log(ms);
```

Comment: Should work in theory, doesn't work in practice. E.g. Safari and Firefox produce different results. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: @RobG - I changed it, so now it should work on all browsers.

Comment: Yes, manual parse, consider `let [y, m, d, hr, min, sec] = dateStr.split(/\D/)`. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can pass that entire string to `Date.parse()` to get the milliseconds.

A caveat though: As others have pointed out, your date lacks a timezone so you'll be limited to the timezone in which the script is run.

```js
const millis = Date.parse('2020-08-18T08:00:00');
console.log(millis);
console.log(new Date(millis));
```

Comment: And parsing is inconsistent, Safari returns a different result to other browsers.

Comment: Yeah sure, because the time passed isn't accurate, so Safari will give the local time vs other implementations that provide UTC.

Comment: That format is supposed to be parsed as local but Safari parses it as UTC.